# How to remove WHOLE words from a string in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function to remove whole words from a string in python, and I think I have something that does it:

```
def remove_words_from_str(strn, word, replacement=' '): 
    return re.sub(r'(\s*)'+word+'(\s*)', replacement, strn)
```

The problem is this takes pieces of words too, which I don't want.

```
EX:  print( remove_words_from_str( "is this is a test ? yes this is ; this is", "is" ) )
OUT:  th  a test ? yes th  ; th
```

Is there a way to only take whole words? (In other words, I don't want 'this' to go to 'th', cause the 'is' in 'this' is not a full word)

Comment: Did you mean `\s+`? `*` means *zero* or more.

Comment: It has to be 0 or more on both sides to cover the first and last word in a string

Comment: zero means that it can be in the middle of a word...

Comment: I do that same line with + instead of * I get:
'is this a test ? yes this ; this is'
Which is not what I want

Comment: I've posted an answer that should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
def remove_words_from_str(strn, word, replacement=' '): 
    return re.sub(r'(^|\s+)'+word+'($|\s+)', replacement, strn)
```

Comment: THIS WORKS! THANKS

Comment: You technically need an `r` in front of the second string. You are getting away with this because `\s` is not a recognized escape sequence (same problem my answer had, except I was using `\b`, which is backspace).

Answer (score 4):

Python regex supports a `\b` symbol, which means "word" boundary. So you can do

```
re.sub(r'\s*\b' + word + r'\b\s*', replacement, strn)
```

You will still want to keep the greedy `\s*` quantifiers on both sides to replace all the surrounding spaces with a single space.

The output for your test case is

```
' this a test ? yes this ; this '
```

If you want to ensure that the first and last space are removed, use `str.strip` on the result:

```
def remove_words_from_str(strn, word, replacement=' '): 
    return re.sub(r'\s*\b' + word + r'\b\s*', replacement, strn).strip()
```

Comment: Doesn't `word` need to be sanitized to protect characters that have a special meaning in re?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux. That depends. One possible use-case is where you would actually allow injection, another is where you would escape it, and a third is where you would forbid any non-letter characters at all. Here, I've assumed that we're all consenting adults

Comment: @user5888527. I forgot the second `r` prefix. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.split()` method on the list to break it down into single words (splits at blanks if no argument is given). And then simply go with

```
list.remove(elem)
```

Comment: `list.remove()` only removes the first occurrence, not all matches of the word.

Answer (score 0):

solution without using a regex:

```
def remove_words_from_str(strn, word, replacement=' '): 
    return " ".join([replacement if token==word else token for token in strn.split()])
```